# Offline Web Application HTML5 on Android

Tags: android, ios, html, web-applications

I want to develop a HTML5 Web App.
I read that in HTML5, you can use the new feature "Offline Web Applications"
With the *.manifest file

I read an article from november 2010, that this feature only works on the iOS platform.

Does it work on Android now?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It works on Android as well as iOS and most desktop browsers. You don't need PhoneGap unless you want to access native features or deploy to the App store.

UPDATE:

Check out [this chapter](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/chapOfflineApplicationCache.html) from Jonathan Stark's book: Building Android Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: okey... thanks... because I dont want to do that with PhoneGap.

Can you write me how I solve that? A example or something else.

I tried it but when i open the site with my Android phone and close it after 1 minute and disable the internet connection.
The browser said, that no connections is available.

Comment: That usually happens if the manifest file is not just right (especially the MIME type). It will work if you get it right. My team developed a product that works that way. Did you look at Jonathan Stark's chapter on this that I linked to?

Comment: Also, it works exactly the same on iOS and Chrome on windows; so, test it there first.

Comment: your link (http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/chapOfflineApplicationCache.html) isn't accessbile anymore, the content is now part of this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010067.do

Answer (score 1):

In general, http://mobilehtml5.org/ provides nice mobile compatibility tables to answer this and other similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.  Here's an example for an offline game:

http://www.davidgranado.com/2010/11/make-a-set-mobile/

The one thing that sucks is that iOS generates a nice icon automatically.  However, android doesn't.  Also, I noticed that on random versions of android, it will display an error popup about the fact that it can't connect to the internet, but still runs fine after that.